# error while creating the control- rsweb-Reportviewer in VS2017

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to add a report to my project in MVC Asp.net, (Visual Studio 2017). the problem after adding (after many tries)the package and when I wanted to add the report to my format I got this error: `the server tag 'rsweb:ReportViewer'  is ambiguous.modify the associated registration that causes ambiguity and choose a new tag prefix`
this is my code in `.aspx` page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server"></rsweb:ReportViewer>

            </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks for help.
This is what I have when I want to add other items in Tools Box:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Y5I.png)

Comment: it looks like you have multiple `TagPrefix="rsweb"`

Comment: I have to Reportviewer not checked in the elements of tools box.as it shown in the screenshot above.